# How to do session management in angularjs after login

Tags: angularjs

HI all am new to angularjs am using java service call for login.on login click button am sending username and password to the server using post method.
As a responce am getting userId.I Want to use that userId throughout the application.
But after login when I click refresh am unable to hold the userId in my rootScope.

My question is with out using localStorage how Can I handle the user Login session
in angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is client side framework and doesn't support anything similar to sessions on server so in order to store something either you need to use localstorage or you will have to save that data on server in session variables or in your database.